# Which db should I choose for my transaction logging

Tags: sql, database, database-design, design-decisions, nosql

I have a database question. I am developing an application where users sends some request and gets an answer from a vendor. I have a server receiving the request (through a rest call or a running web service, haven't decided which yet).

Whenever a new request comes in it should be logged in a database and when the vendor responds the record should be updated indicating whether it was accepted or not and stuff like that. The only reason for this storage of transactions is for reporting and logging purposes. So now that I have stated my requirement I need help from someone with more expertise in this.

What I've come up with so far is that it would be best to use a structured database since all records will have one type and the same information, so there's no need to waste space using a semi-structured database with each record containing both structure and information.

But I don't know if there are any databases that are particularly good for this kind of "create/update operations only" ?? As I said I only need to read the data perhaps once a month or so.
Any inputs are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any open source database like postgreSql as you are mostly going to do inserts and not much other features needed. My suggestion will try to put logging process in separate threads rather than the one  you are using for processing to have better performance for your api calls.

Comment: it will be better if you can tell in which  programming  language you are working in this application

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a application with a lot of create/update queries and currently using [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org).
It's fast and really good with j2E and php. NoSQL is really fast to learn with it, and the web interface is really user friendly :)

Comment: That looks interesting I will check it out! If it matches my needs I will accept the answer :)